# Computer won't start/react while new gpu is plugged in

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, power, gpu

I just upgraded my computer and changed almost everything except for the case and psu (650W).

My parts:

- ASUS ROG MAXIMUS VII HERO
- Intel Core i7-4790K
- Kingston SSDNow V300 240GB 2.5" OEM
- Corsair Vengeance DDR3 1600MHz 8GB x2
- PSU (not sure of exact name) Nitro Series 650C (650W)
- MSI GeForce GTX 980 Gaming 4GB

Everything works perfectly fine as long as the gpu is not plugged in. It boots up, and runs smoothly. But with the gpu plugged in it doesn't even react when I try turning it on. It simply does nothing.

I tried using my old gpu and it starts, but with the 980 no reaction.

Comment: Sounds like the card is bad. Have you contacted MSI to see if there are troubleshooting or diagnostics tools available?

Comment: It's also possible that the PSU isn't powerful enough for the GPU and CPU. What wattage is your old PSU?

Comment: It says it is 650W, is it possible that it gets less effective over time. Since it is starting to get a bit old?

Comment: you connected power to both plugs? 6 and 8 pin

Comment: I have conected everything. The msi 980 takes two 8 pins. I made sure multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with a Radeon R9 280X. You should be able to fix your problem by booting without the graphics card plugged in, so you need to plug your screen on the motherboard. In your bios, select 'display from onboard graphics' instead of pci express (if not already done). Then restart your computer.
When you are on your desktop with Windows loaded, plug your graphics card in on your motherboard and then install your card drivers. Try not to touch anything else while you plug your card since your computer is on.

Finally, reboot and select 'display on pci express' in your bios.
Hope it helps.